# Multilevel hasMany sideloading

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, active-model-serializers

I use `ActiveModel::Serializers` to get JSON out to an Ember.js application. I use sideloading to maximize the performance.

Can I tell `ActiveModel::Serializers` to sideload all `PhoneNumbers` in the `SwitchboardSerializer`?

**switchboard_serializer.rb**

```
class SwitchboardSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, :include => true

  attributes :id, :name
  has_many :switchboard_entries
  has_many :sip_accounts, :through => :switchboard_entries
end
```

**sip_account_serializer.rb**

```
class SipAccountSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, :include => true

  attributes :id, :auth_name, :caller_name, :sip_accountable_id
  has_many :phone_numbers
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `has_many :phone_numbers, :through => :sip_accounts` into `app/models/switchboard.rb` I was able to use `has_many :phone_numbers` in `switchboard_serializer.rb`. :-)